# Oracle UCM -Custom Service creation

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-ucm

I have a requirement where in i need to merge some contents(Documents) into a
Single Document and send it back to the Front end ADF Application for a user to
download it.
I 'm trying to create a custom service which will accept the parameters in the
form of an Array List -something like ["Doc,ContentID1,ContentID
2","Document,ContentID3,ContentID4"],Where DOc and Document will be the name of
the merged documents and ContentID1,ContentID2 will be the contents to be merged
and form a new document "Doc" and ContentID3,ContentID4 will be merged and form
a new document "Document" and both these documents are sent back to the
application.

If I create a custom service where can I define what type of parameters will it
accept.
Any help/pointers is appreciated.
TIA

Answer (score 2):

Parameters for services are similar to standard html GET parameters, i.e. they are just strings (so the answer is no, you can't "define what type of parameters will it accept" - they are *always* strings). Once a service is called all parameters are available in m_binder.

In your case call like:

```
http://<ucm_host>/<ucm_instance>/idcplg?IdcService=MEGE_DOCUMENTS&merge1=docName1,contentId1,contentId2&merge2=docName2,contentId1,contentId2
```

will run custom service MEGE_DOCUMENTS with 2 parameters - merge1 and merge2 - in m_binder.
You may get them like this:

```
String parameter1 = m_binder.getLocal("merge1");
String parameter2 = m_binder.getLocal("merge2");
```

after that parameter1 will have value "*docName1,contentId1,contentId2*" and parameter2 - "*docName2,contentId1,contentId2*"

---

So, if this service is supposed to be run independently (e.g. from browser / as a separate service) - I'm afraid you'll have to iterate through parameters. 
Like this, for example (I know it is ugly, but it's all you can do in your situation):

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
String prefix = "merge"; 
int index = 1; 
boolean hasMoreParams = true; 

while(hasMoreParams) { 
    String paramName = prefix + index;
    if(m_binder.m_localData.containsKey(paramName)) {
        String paramValue = m_binder.getLocal(paramName); 
        params.put(paramName, paramValue); 
        index++; 
    } else { 
        hasMoreParams = false; 
    } 
}
```

---

In case your service will be used by other services/filters (i.e. called from java code *only*) you may put any java object (e.g. HashMap) in binder's local data before service call and then use it:

```
m_binder.m_localData.put(<Object>, <Object>);
```

Do not mix up m_localData with m_binder.putLocal(). 
m_localData is a Property variable (an extension of HashTable).
putLocal() is a method which have only one String parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the solution,but what I'm looking for is there can be more than 2 documents required for merging so at the component end or in the custom java code how am i going to get these parameters. In this case :                                                          http://<ucm_host>/<ucm_instance>/idcplg?IdcService=MEGE_DOCUMENTS&merge1=docName1,contentId1,contentId2&merge2=docName2,contentId1,contentId2&merge3=doc3,C3,C4&merge4=Dco4,c5,c6 and so on.So how will i Come to know that this service has got more than one parameters?

Comment: Could you please specify how exactly your service will be called? 
In case it will be used by other services/filters (i.e. called from java code) you may put any java object (e.g. HashMap) in binder's local data before service call and then use it. In case this service is supposed to be run independently (e.g. from browser / as a separate service) - I'm afraid you'll have to iterate through parameters.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail,This service will be called from custom Java code from an ADF application so i guess the first approach of putting java objects might work for me.What say?

Comment: I tried to push the java object  in the binder's local data,but it seems it only accepts the String value..Is there any other way out to achieve this?

Comment: Just use binder's m_localData variable (which type is an extension of the HashTable), not the putLocal() method: m_binder.m_localData.put(<Object>, <Object>);

Comment: Moving recap of all these comments to my answer